# jQuery /deep/ delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-component, shadow-dom

With webcomponents, you can target inner elements of the shadowdom using `/deep/`, which works fine until I try to utilize event delegation.

A regular click function will work:

```
$('html /deep/ a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('foo')
})
```

Delegation seems to have no effect:

```
$('html').on('click', '/deep/ a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('bar')
})
```

Any idea what to do here?

Comment: I don't think events bubble out of web components (by default at least), so delegation can't work.

Comment: Haven't tried, but I'm guessing the elements bubble to the `ShadowRoot`, and no further, so attaching the handler to `<html>` is probably useless.

Comment: can you not add the click handler **inside** the polymer element itself?

Comment: @Todd I think `$(document)` is pretty much the same as `$("html")`, at least in this case. If the events don't bubble to one, they won't bubble to the other.

Comment: wow. yeah. not sure what I thought that'd accomplish. disregard.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow DOM retargets events so they appear to come from the host element. This is to preserve the encapsulation model (otherwise you could grab the target and muck around inside a component).

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-events

Maybe you could try to delegate to the host element and then use `event.path` to figure out if an `a` was clicked?